# MacOS Launchd move files plist in Ventura not working

Tags: terminal, plist, schedule, launchd, macos-ventura

I am trying to schedule two zsh commands every 10 seconds

The plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.david.pdf</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/David/Tools/pdf.txt</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And the script

```
#!/bin/zsh
mv ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/*.pdf ~/dropbox/reading/temp
mv ~/dropbox/*.pdf ~/dropbox/reading/temp
```

I'm wanting to copy all PDF files from Books and from the root of Dropbox, to a selected /Reading/Temp folder

My script does not work, with error 78.

Both work fine from terminal

What am I doing wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your script and making it executable.

```
mv pdf.txt pdf.sh && chmod +x pdf.sh
```

Also, if launchd is anything like cron, then 10 seconds might be too short. Consider using 60 seconds minimum.

Comment: Great, thanks - that did the trick . . .

Comment: @DavidHarris You might want to check out the documentation too, `WatchPaths` and `QueueDirectories` might be helpful to trigger the script when the path is not empty or has changed. And enable debugging. See `man launchd.plist`. Instead of moving files from Apple Books, you could create symlinks and save resources. See [Can Dropbox sync symlinks?](https://help.dropbox.com/sync/symlinks#:~:text=On%20computers%20running%20macOS%20or,no%20longer%20work%20as%20intended.)

Comment: A quick followon, I use Apple Books as an 'inbox' for Dropbox because it's so easy to save to from multiple devices, so move rather than copy works for my workflow.  Other than that, your script suggestion works perfectly, and 20 seconds is fine.  Any ideas how to copy but not override if duplicates do exist - so to rename as unique names, where duplicates exist.

Comment: To move without overwriting using mv, I would do another shell script (based on mv) that takes a source filename and destination folder as arguments, checks if the source filename already exists, and if it does, append a number to the end before calling mv. Otherwise you could use the -n option in your script to prevent overwriting. But to be fair it's probably worth a new question. If you found my answer helpful please consider voting, cheers